# R: deSolve - partial differential equation

Tags: r, differential-equations

Could somebody help me with the R package **deSolve**/**ReacTran**, which can be used for solving any parabolic partial differential equation:

[image: PDE for bond pricing, from Cox-Ingresoll-Ross model]

I have found a similar example in the book 
**Karline Soetaert, Jeff_Cash, Francesca Mazzia: Solving Partial Differential Equations in R**, chapter 9, page 179-181, 
where is a solution for  the equation:

[image: The Nonlinear Schrodinger Equation]

Online version of book: [Solving Partial Differential Equations in R](http://b-ok.cc/ireader/1305636)

The PDE and the solution is defined like:

```
Schrodinger <- function(t, u, parms) {
du <- 1i * tran.1D (C = u, D = 1, dx = xgrid)$dC +
1i * gam * abs(u)ˆ2 * u
list(du) }

N <- 300
xgrid <- setup.grid.1D(-20, 80, N = N)
x <- xgrid$x.mid

out <- ode.1D(y = yini, parms = NULL, func = Schrodinger,
times = times, dimens = 300, method = "adams")
```

There's an example of the second partial derivative:

```
tran.1D (C = u, D = 1, dx = xgrid)$dC
```

but I'm not sure how to define the first partial derivatives in the [PDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pAWy.png)
and for derivatives by **r_e** and **r_d** *(more 'xgrid', or ?)*

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Your PDE is really 2D+time (r_e as x and r_d as y). So you should look more into tran.2D I believe (same goes for grid.2D and ode.2D). Take a look at the full manual cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ReacTran/ReacTran.pdf or cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ReacTran/vignettes/PDE.pdf PS: never tried `r` so I won't venture at an answer